# How do I depend on all properties of an Ember Object?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to create a property which represents an Object stringified. It should update whenever any sub property of the object changes even if it isnt a direct child.

I.e.

```
var obj = Ember.Object.extend({jsonString: Ember.something()}).create({foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: Ember.Object.create({bam: Ember.A([1, 2, 3])})});
expect(obj.get('jsonString')).to.equal('{"foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": {"bam": [1, 2, 3]}}');
obj.set('foo', 3);
expect(obj.get('jsonString')).to.equal('{"foo": 3, "bar": 2, "baz": {"bam": [1, 2, 3]}}');
obj.set('foo.baz.dd', 'test');
expect(obj.get('jsonString')).to.equal('{"foo": 3, "bar": 2, "baz": {"dd": "test", "bam": [1, 2, 3]}}');
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't, as this is a potential performance black hole. What's the use case? Could a helper do the job?

Comment: Im not worried about performance, I want to create a mixin with some debug features (this is not for production, only for debugging and one of the reasons that I dont want to change the production code). This mixin will log the json string whenever it changes so that I can see exactly how the data is changing.

Comment: Why not use Ember Inspector?

Comment: I want to use it for logging, where you may not know that there is a problem,  but you want to know what happened in retrospective (im also using an electron app which makes it harder)